# Como definir um tempo limite para uma requisição JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em JAVA, Android Studio, e preciso fazer algumas requisições JSON.

Para tanto criei uma classe AsyncTask e faço assim no doInBackground:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String command = strings[0];
        String json;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(command);
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic c3VwZXI6MTIzNA==");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                ...
```

O problema ocorre quando o servidor não responde, seja por estar off ou lento mesmo...gostaria de definir um tempo limite para a requisição.

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Sugiro que utilize o retrofit ao invés do AsyncTask, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380844/how-to-set-timeout-in-retrofit-library) você pode encontrar como mudar o tempo de requisição do retrofit. espero ter ajudado

Comment: Porém, se não for a resolução ideal. há uma duplicata da sua pergunta na comunidade oficial [Android Setting a timeout for an AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)